# clicking on acre app results in 404 pages from freebase wiki

Tags: freebase, freebase-acre

I am a newbie trying to use Acre app. But if I click on any Acre app, it simply results in 404 error page. I tried searching on web but It seems it is working for everyone else and no one have faced this issue. I am wondering , what could be missing which is causing this 404 error ? Do I need to register first ?
e.g. http://teste2.pedroerfn.user.dev.freebaseapps.com/
http://lifebits.micktaiwan.user.dev.freebaseapps.com/
In my machine all are 404 pages :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire Acre system has been [retired](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/freebase-discuss/miqOEnD9YX4/b_KAX_wgr5EJ%5C).  No user apps deployed on freebaseapps.com work any more.